# Is there a Levenshtein distance in PMML standard? How do you calculate it?

Tags: pmml

I am trying to get Levenshtein distance between two fields using PMML.  Is there an easy implimentation of this?

I have looked at this :

http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-2-1/Transformations.html

but it's not clear to me if I can use this to calculate Levenshtein distance and where this might fit into my pmml document.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "standalone" function for computing the Levenshtein distance between two string values.

If you want to perform string comparison, then you should check out the [TextIndex](http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-3/Transformations.html#xsdElement_TextIndex) transformation. The `TextIndex` element has `maxLevenshteinDistance` attribute, which can be used to implement queries like "is string value A equal to string value B if the maximum allowed Levenshtein distance is X".

```
<TextIndex textField="myStringField" localTermWeights="binary" maxLevenshteinDistance="3">
  <Constant dataType="string">Hello World!</Constant>
</TextIndex>
```

The above should return `1` if the input string value `myStringField` is less than three edits away from the reference string value `Hello String` (and `0` otherwise).

Comment: I saw this but I need more specific example on how to use this to calculate the stat.  You basically recommended what I already linked to in my question.